# java - making a set of functions all return unique values without hard-coding numbers?

Tags: java, preprocessor, return-value

I have a set of functions and I would like each one to return a different prime number. I don't care which function returns which prime, but they must all be distinct.

What I'd like to be able to do is write something like:

```
return #uniquePrime#;
```

And then have all of these converted to actual numbers when I compile the code.

Is this possible? Or something with a similar effect? (other than hard-coding a set of prime numbers)

Thanks!

Comment: Java doesn't come with a preprocessor. What third-party preprocessor are you using?

Comment: What you are asking to do doesn't make any sense--either you haven't analyzed and broken down your problem well enough or it's a homework assignment.  Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JKK: Your design is broken. Rather than trying to hack a solution into a language, re-think your design. What are you actually trying to *accomplish* that you think unique primes from functions will solve?

Comment: @Ted Hopp - I'm just using the standard compiler, and was fairly sure it didn't have any form of preprocessor, but was hoping I'd be wrong :-)

Comment: @BillK and StefanKendall - This came up while writing code for some machine learning research. Each function is a separate feature and it would be conveinet for each to return a unique prime as I would then have simple unique IDs for each feature, and any combination of features (by multiplication). There are alternatives (both in terms of numbers to use and implementation approach), but I couldn't see how this approach could be done in Java, so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Also, sorry for the extremely slow response - I misunderstood the e-mail notification settings and had expected I would receive mail when someone commented or responded to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or something with a similar effect?

Although I don't understand why you want to do this. You could create a

method `nextPrime("methodName")` which creates a prime number and registers it in a `HashMap<String,Integer>` where String is the method name received as argument and Integer stores the prime. If the method is called again you can lookup whether the prime number was already calculated and return it. You can check the HashMap to see if a prime number was already used for another method.

Instead of `return #uniquePrime#;`

you would `return nextPrime("methodName");`

Comment: Looks good - the only drawback is that I assume this won't be compiled out, so there will be a slight performance cost (though from the comments so far I gather that just isn't possible in Java).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a singleton prime number generator, and invoke it from a static block in each of the class:

```
class Foo {
    private static final int PRIME;

    static {
        PRIME = PrimeNumberGenerator.getInstance().nextPrime();
    }

    public int getPrime() {
        return PRIME;
    }
}
```

The prime number generator is left to you as an exercise. But if the number of primes is small, using a fixed set of numbers to implement it is the easiest solution.

Comment: don't forget to synchronize the nextPrime method if the code is multi threaded

Comment: +1 good solution! I second the suggestion of using a fixed list of primes because calculating them can be costly. You can steal the list of known primes of the net for up to very high values; just stick em in a constant or a file or something...

Comment: Sadly this doesn't quite suit my needs as I was hoping for a unique prime for a set of methods, rather than for a set of calsses. Of course I could have static variables, one per method, but in that case I might as well hard-code those to be a set of unique primes.

Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 1):

If you have purpose to generate huge number of similar methods in test environment you can use a method signature or line number as an input data.
E.g.

```
public int method1() {
    return primeValue();
}

private static int primeValue() {
    final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    final StackTraceElement lastElement = stackTrace[2];
    return lastElement.getLineNumber();
}
```

Be carefull. This code has perfomance leak.

Answer (score 0):

a solution without a preprocessor: you could write a function that return prime numbers. somthing like getPrime(). each function could call this method to recive a prime number. if getPrime() return each number only one  time, the numbers will be unique. you could store the numbers in a map or fields to get the corresponding number for the method.

```
int getANumber() {
    if(value1 == null)
        value1 = getPrime();
    return value1;
}
int getASecondNumber() {
    if(value2 == null)
        value2 = getPrime();
    return value2;
}
```

but why you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks - this matches the previous suggestion above.

As for why I want to do this, see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to attack this. It's rather hard to do as a collection of functions in a single class. A slight variant, though, can work quite well: use function objects instead of functions. Built-in versions of this in Java are the [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interfaces. Here's a home-grown variant, along with the outlines of a supporting class:

```
/** A class that returns a sequence of unique primes. */
class PrimeNumberStream {
    private int nextIndex = 0;

    /** Return the next prime in this stream. */
    public int nextPrime() {
        return getNextPrime(nextIndex++);
    }

    private static int getNextPrime(int index) {
        // TODO - return the index-th prime number
    }
}

class UniquePrimeFunction {
    private static final PrimeNumberStream primes = new PrimeNumberStream();

    /** The prime that this function object will return. */
    private final int mPrime;

    public UniquePrimeFunction() {
        mPrime = primes.nextPrime();
    }

    public int call() {
        return mPrime;
    }
}

// Define an array of function objects, each of which returns a unique prime.
UniquePrimeFunction[] functions = {
    new UniquePrimeFunction(),
    new UniquePrimeFunction(),
    // etc.
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // print each function's unique prime
    for (UniquePrimeFunction func : functions) {
        System.out.println(func.call());
    }
}
```

Each element of the `functions` array will return a different int value from its `call` method. This could have also been done using the Callable interface, but that would have required using Integer values instead of ints.

Comment: Cool, I can see some other potential advantages in terms of associating extra info with the features.